# Is it possible to horizontally center align full width div list items inside other container div?

Tags: html, css

Picture describes it better, so I am attaching it.

[image: a desired result]

So, this is simple list. Green areas are clickable and what I want to achieve is centering texts inside those green buttons, but those texts also should be aligned to left side. Not sure if I am being clear enough, but I do hope picture will explain the idea.

Tried to play with flex, but not successfully.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}


.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="otherContainer">
    <div class="item">some text</div>
    <div class="item">sone loooonger text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect to have some clean css which would allow me to have desired result as you can see in picture. So, question is, is it even possible to achieve without hackish css/JS solutions?

Comment: yes it's possible, share your code

Comment: CSS grid? That's what I'd go for.

Comment: Padding will help you

Comment: this is what I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/q16nt3b8/1/ so, basically I need text to stay in same position, just spread item divs to be in full width :)

Comment: how padding can help here if I need those texts to be centered? :) p.s. it should be responsive as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible to do this without javascript, but it comes with some limitations like having to set a max-width.

```css
button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}

div {
  margin: 1rem auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
}

.bg-lightgreen {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button class="bg-green">
  <div>Some text</div>
</button>

<button class="bg-lightgreen">
  <div>Some other text</div>
</button>

<button class="bg-green">
  <div>Text</div>
</button>
```

Comment: @tdk this is your answer

Comment: Johnson, you can avoid that limitation by changing the max-width: 20% for example. or any percent

Comment: this would totally work, but thing is it only works if max-width matches longest text in list width. meaning that if some long text will be added, max-width should be changed accordingly. and as I am getting that list dynamically, I don't know what will appear inside those buttons. setting % is better, but still not bulletproof. anyway, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick using table:

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  display:table-row;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.item:before,
.item:after{
  content: "";
  display:table-cell;
  width:50%;
}

.item:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">some text</div>
  <div class="item">sone loooonger text</div>
  <div class="item">text</div>
</div>
```